# How does Javascript's URL() constructor work behind the scenes (getter/setter weirdness)

Tags: javascript, oop

Trying to figure out what's going on behind the scenes of the URL() constructor (and other native Javascript APIs). When I try to create an object with a normal prop that also has a setter, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Invalid property descriptor. Cannot both specify accessors and a value or writable attribute
```

But notice with instantiating a new URL(), you CAN log out the object, see all the normal enumerable props, and yet those same props have custom setter behavior:

```
const u = new URL('http://google.com/example/path');
console.log(u);

  {
    // all of these are normal props:
    hostname: 'google.com',
    pathname: '/example/path',
    href: 'http://google.com/example/path'
  }

u.pathname = '/new-example/path';
console.log(u);

  {
    // notice that pathname AND href have changed, presumably from setter
    // behavior, but they're still regular, enumerable, non-getter props:
    hostname: 'google.com',
    pathname: '/new-example/path',
    href: 'http://google.com/new-example/path'
  }
```

Explanation would be great or point to URL() source... thanks!

Comment: _"they're still regular, enumerable, non-getter props"_ no, if you look at the prototype you will see they are setters and getters, https://i.imgur.com/VoBySrYl.jpg. And if you look at the [WhatWG spec](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#api) you will see they refer to each property's getter / setter

Comment: @PatrickEvans but if you console.log the object, the props themselves are just strings; i see the prototype has getters/setters. when i try to replicate this implementation, my instance object has the getter/setter function *on the instance*

Comment: The prototype holds the methods that instances get.... you see the props as strings as that is what the getters returns

Comment: @PatrickEvans Unfortunately hard to describe in text, but with native URL() implementation when you log the instance in Chrome Dev console, the props appear as strings. With my implementation, using getter/setter on prototype, they appear as `(...)` that resolve when clicked. This is a very minor issue since `typeof prop` still returns string... was just curious what is happening BTS that's different

Answer (score -2):

> Explanation would be great or point to URL() source... thanks!

[URL API (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) --> [URL Standard (WHATWG)](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#api)